# Unity and Gnome lock screens appear at the same time

Tags: unity, gnome, lock-screen, 18.04

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and tried to change the default look to vanilla Gnome following [How To Get Stock Gnome Shell In Ubuntu 17.10](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/get-stock-gnome-shell-in-ubuntu-17-10/) instructions. Everything seems to work fine, except when I lock my computer I get both Gnome-looking and Unity-looking lock screens (like those shown [Meet the Improved Ubuntu 17.10 Login Screen](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/09/ubuntu-17-10-login-screen-preview)). The Gnome one is visible after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and unity after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

How to remove the Unity-looking screen?